# Probability Question 3.17 in Wackerly, Mendenhall, and Scheaffer, 5th Ed.

Tags: probability, expected-value

> **Problem 3.17.** Two construction contracts are to be randomly assigned to one or more of three firms:
>   I, II, and III. Any firm may receive both contracts. If each contract will yield a profit of
>   $\$90,000$ for the firm, find the expected profit for firm I. If firms I and II are actually owned
>   by the same individual, what is the owner's expected total profit?

**My Answer.** Let $Y$ be the number of contracts assigned to firm I. Then this problem is equivalent to
indistinguishable balls put into distinguishable urns, where the urns can be empty. That means
the number of ways to assign $2$ indistinguishable contracts to $3$ distinguishable firms is
$$\binom{2+3-1}{2}=\binom{4}{2}=6. $$
It follows that the distribution for $Y$ is as follows:
$$
\begin{array}{c|c|c|c}
y      &0    &1    &2    \\ \hline
P(Y=y) &1/2  &1/3  &1/6
\end{array}
$$
This means that the expected profit, given by $E(\$90000Y),$
is
$$E(\$90000Y)=\$90000\left[0/2+1/3+2/6\right]=\$60000. $$
Now if one owner owns two firms, let $X$ be a random variable describing how many contracts either
company I or II got. This essentially coalesces the two companies I and II in terms of our analysis. 
We have the following probability distribution for $X:$
$$
\begin{array}{c|c|c|c}
x      &0    &1    &2    \\ \hline
P(X=x) &1/3  &1/3  &1/3
\end{array}
$$
It follows that the expected value for the total profit is given by
$$E(\$90000X)=\$90000[0/3+1/3+2/3]=\$90000. $$

> **My Question.** The answer in the back of the book, however, is $\$120000.$ Why is that? Is there an error in my reasoning? Thanks in advance for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a problem with your reasoning: each combination is not just as likely to occur. If each contract has a probability of $\frac{1}{3}$ to go to one of the firms, than the probabilities are as follows:

$$P(0) = \frac{2}{3} \cdot \frac{2}{3} = \frac{4}{9}$$
$$P(1) = \frac{2}{3} \cdot \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{3} \cdot \frac{2}{3} = \frac{4}{9}$$
$$P(2) = \frac{1}{3} \cdot \frac{1}{3} = \frac{1}{9}$$

We find:

$$E[X] = \frac{4}{9} \cdot 0 + \frac{4}{9} \cdot 90000 + \frac{1}{9} \cdot 180000 = 60000$$

You could also arrive here by dividing the total expected profit for all companies by the number of companies, or $180000$ divided by three. If one individual owns both companies, we can simply multiply by two and arrive at $120000$. Alternatively:

$$P(0) = \frac{1}{3} \cdot \frac{1}{3} = \frac{1}{9}$$
$$P(1) = \frac{2}{3} \cdot \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{3} \cdot \frac{2}{3} = \frac{4}{9}$$
$$P(2) = \frac{2}{3} \cdot \frac{2}{3} = \frac{4}{9}$$

We then find:

$$E[X] = \frac{1}{9} \cdot 0 + \frac{4}{9} \cdot 90000 + \frac{4}{9} \cdot 180000 = 120000$$

Comment: Sorry, in your first series of probability calculations, what's the random variable for which you're finding the distribution? Oh, my $Y$, I guess.

Comment: I was a little unsure of the "dividing by three" method, because of unions/intersections, and things not always adding up the way you expect. That's why I wanted to find the distribution and calculate the expected value according to the usual formula.

Comment: @AdrianKeister I understand your concerns. Both approaches are applicable, so just use whatever you feel most comfortable with!

Comment: Could you please provide a little more detail on your second probability calculations? It's not quite clear to me, yet, how you arrived at them, although no doubt they are correct.

Comment: I'm so confused! It looks to me like, for the first part, you're getting the same answer I am, but by a different route. Is reducing the problem to indistinguishable balls being put into distinguishable urns with empty urns allowed not a valid reduction? If it is valid, then the formula for putting $n$ indistinguishable balls into $k$ distinguishable urns with empty urns allowed is $\binom{k+n-1}{n}.$ This was the backbone of my approach to both parts of the problem. Is this not a correct way of thinking about the problem?

Comment: @AdrianKeister Your reasoning is indeed incorrect: each combination is not just as likely to occur. It's just a coincidence that you arrive at the same number this way. For example, consider giving the two contracts to the first firm. According to you, the probability of this happening equals $\frac{1}{6}$. In reality, however, it's $\frac{1}{3} \cdot \frac{1}{3} = \frac{1}{9}$, or the probability that the first contract goes to this firm times the probability that the second contract goes to this firm. The same reasoning applies to the second problem, although here there are two companies!

Comment: That's helpful, thanks. So how do you get at $P(1)?$ You have numbers there, but not words to help explain them.

Comment: The probability of getting one contract equals the probability that you don't get the first contract times the probability that you get the second, plus the probability that you get the first contract times the probability that you don't get the second, or $\frac{2}{3} \cdot \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{3} \cdot \frac{2}{3} = \frac{4}{9}$.

Comment: That makes it look like you're treating the contracts as distinguishable. Are they? Because if the contracts are distinguishable, then there are $3^2=9$ ways to assign the contracts.

Comment: @AdrianKeister That's correct, hence the denominator!

Comment: I think that was my fundamental error: thinking that the contracts were indistinguishable. Many thanks for your time!